# Adding strings to nested lists of strings if list doesn't already contain said string

Tags: python, string, list, nested-lists

Sorry for the clumsy title. I'm trying to learn Python and I thought I'd organize my Skyrim book collections at the same time. (For generic description see next paragraph). I've got three bookcases, one in Whiterun, one in Markarth and one in Lakeview Manor. I'm trying to make a function which takes in the name of a book, searches a list, (containing 3 strings and 3 further lists), and if the book is already in one of my libraries, give me a message saying I already have that book. If the book isn't in one of the libraries, add it to an appropriate nested list.

I have a list, containing strings and nested lists of strings, I want to add a string to the nested lists of string but only if the string is not in one of the nested lists already.

```
 library = [ 'Whiterun', ['Book of Riddles', 'Dragonborn'], 'Markarth', ['Dwemer History'], 'Lakeview', ['Nightingales', 'Werewolves'] ]
```

What would be the best way to search the library for a given book?

Comment: "add it to an appropriate nested list" could you give an example for that? How would you know, which one is the appropriate one?

Comment: eg, add_book('Dragonborn', library, 'Whiterun')... So then I check the name of the house, if its Whiterun I add it to the first nested list, if its Markarth I add it to the second nested list. This was my idea anyway

Comment: Did you already run across Dicts (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)?

Comment: I know this is partly an exercise, but a good solution to your problem would be a database, and Python happens to have a [sqlite3 interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). Just a suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order is not an issue, use a dict with sets as values holding the names of the book:

```
 library = {'Whiterun':{'Book of Riddles', 'Dragonborn'}, 
           'Markarth': {'Dwemer History'}, 
           'Lakeview': {'Nightingales', 'Werewolves'} }
```

Then do a lookup, returning a message if you already have the book added or adding the book to the section:

```
def add_book(section, book, lib):
    if book in lib[section]:
        return "Already added {}".format(book)
    library[section].add(book)
```

You would also want to handle the case where the section might not exist giving an appropriate message when the lookup fails:

```
def lookup(section, book, lib):
    try:
        if book in lib[section]:
            return "Already added"
    except KeyError:
        return "Invalid section {}".format(section)
    library[section].add(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very brief and rough sketch, how this could look like with a dict:

```
library = {}
library['Whiterun'] = ['Book of Riddles', 'Dragonborn']
library['Markarth'] = ['Dwemer History']
library['Lakeview'] = ['Nightingales', 'Werewolves']

def add_book_to_lib(library, case, book):
  if case in library:
    if book in library[case]:
      print('{0} already exists in {1}'.format(book,case))
    else:
      library[case].append(book)
      print('Added book {0}'.format(book))

  else:
    library[case] = [book]
    print('Created new case {0}'.format(case))

add_book_to_lib(library, 'Whiterun', 'Dragonborn')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a work around solution which is a bit simpler than my original idea but does the job I want. It stores the books in 3 separate lists and thus 3 separate text files using pickle for file serialization. Although it doesn't follow python naming conventions because I'm going to have about 400 function signatures to type out so I just went for all capitals for the ease.

```
'''
Program to track what books I have in my libraries in 3 seperate houses in
skyrim: Whiterun, Markarth, Lakeview Manor
Uses 3 seperate lists for the 3 diff houses.
'''

import pickle

WHITERUN = []
MARKARTH = []
LAKEVIEW = []



def print_lib(library):
     for each_book in library:
          print(each_book)


def have_book(book):
     if WHITERUN.count(book) > 0:
          print('The book: ' + book + ' is already in Whiterun')
          return True
     elif MARKARTH.count(book) > 0:
          print('The book: ' + book + ' is already in Markarth')
          return True
     elif LAKEVIEW.count(book) > 0:
          print('The book: ' + book + ' is already in Lakeview')
          return True
     else:
          return False


def addbook(book, house):
     if not have_book(book):
          house.append(book)
          house.sort()



try:
     with open('whiterun.txt', 'rb') as whiterun_lib:
          WHITERUN = pickle.load(whiterun_lib)
     with open('markarth.txt', 'rb') as markarth_lib:
          MARKARTH = pickle.load(markarth_lib)
     with open('lakeview.txt', 'rb') as lakeview_lib:
          LAKEVIEW = pickle.load(lakeview_lib)
except IOError as err:
     print('File Error: ' +str(err))
except pickle.PicklingError as perr:
     print('Pickling error: ' + str(perr))

print(WHITERUN)
print(MARKARTH)
print(LAKEVIEW)


# whiterun books
addbook('DRAGONBORN', WHITERUN)


# markarth books
addbook('CATS OF SKYRIM', MARKARTH)

#lakeview books
addbook('A DREAM OF SOVNGARDE', LAKEVIEW)

print(WHITERUN)
print(MARKARTH)
print(LAKEVIEW)


try:
     with open('whiterun.txt', 'wb') as whiterun_lib:
          pickle.dump(WHITERUN, whiterun_lib)
     with open('markarth.txt', 'wb') as markarth_lib:
          pickle.dump(MARKARTH, markarth_lib)
     with open('lakeview.txt', 'wb') as lakeview_lib:
          pickle.dump(LAKEVIEW, lakeview_lib)
except IOError as err:
     print('File Error: ' +str(err))
except pickle.PicklingError as perr:
     print('Pickling error: ' + str(perr))
```